# Changing key of input method in ibus

Tags: apt, software-installation, ibus, hunspell

I installed ibus and selected Marathi - itrans(m17n) as input method. It is working as expected.

```
apt install ibus{,-m17n,,-gtk} im-config -y
```

My question is how do I make a few minor changes to the keyboard? In other words, if I need something else on keystroke "l", is that possible?

---

Update:

I copied the following file to /usr/share/m17n/ directory.

https://github.com/shantanuo/spell_check/blob/master/mr-gamabhana.mim

It solved the problem for me. But I am not sure how others will be able to use the file unless it is accepted by ibus package. How do I copy this file to the directory mentioned above using a command like this?

```
apt install gamabhana
```

---

Update 2:

I have crated a deb package that is working as expected.

https://github.com/shantanuo/spell_check/blob/master/gamabhana.deb

How do I submit to apt? Do I need to upload the file somewhere?

---

Update 3:

When I try to install hunspell language packs, it works for Hindi and Gujarathi but not for marathi. In other words this works...

```
apt install hunspell-hi
```

But this does not:

```
apt install hunspell-mr
```

I am not sure where to ask if this is not the right thread.

Comment: That will, I presume, depend on your keyboard layout rather than on ibus.

Comment: `xmodmap` is the easier way, but it does not always work reliably nowadays. Changing keyboard layout is possible, but complicated: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show&redirect=Howto%3A+Custom+keyboard+layout+definitions Anyway, adjust your question. You think it is solved through ibus. It isn' t.

Comment: This sounds like a different question. If you managed to solve this question, then please post the answer: it is fine to answer your own questions. This can help future users.

Comment: `How do I submit to apt? Do I need to upload the file somewhere?` If you have the Debian source, you can create a Launchpad PPA (we can help you build one, if you make the debian source package available on GitHub).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egamabhana-team/+archive/ubuntu/gamabhana) to install Gamabhana.

First, add the repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gamabhana-team/gamabhana
```

Update the software index, and install `gamabhana`.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gamabhana
```

To set it up, open ibus preferences, search for Marathi, and enable gamabhana.

Comment: Should I ask a new question for "update 3"?

Comment: Yes, you should ask one question per question.